# Problems adding Contribution form to a WP page

Tags: contribution-page

I just created a new contribution page in Civi and made sure it was active. When I go to create a new wordpress page and try to insert it I have no options to choose from when I click on the CiviCRM button. The only thing it shows is the dashboard options. How do I get my Civi Contribution form into a wordpress page? Is there some sort of a setting I am missing to get active contribution pages to show up as an option to choose from?

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable all of your plugins (except CiviCRM) and try it again. If you can now see the Civi options, you have a couple of options: a. Set up your page, reactivate your plugins and go on with life, b. Reactivate the plugins one by one to see which is the issue.

If that does not work:

2. Switch to a WP basic theme like Twenty Seventeen or Twenty Sixteen and try the page create again. If you can see the Civi options, I would setup the page, switch back to your theme of choice. Just switch to a basic theme when you need to see the options and then back to your theme for usage.

If you do not want to mess with either above,

3. Under Contributions > Manage Contribution Pages > Select the page you want > Links > Live. This will give you a link that ends in id=#  Below is an example of Civi shortcode. Replace the 2 in the shortcode below with the id# from your live link and paste it to your WP page.
   [civicrm component="contribution" id="2" mode="live" hijack="0"]

Answer (score 0):

Drag the Pop up window over. Usually the drop down is rendered on a lower Z axis than the pop up.

The Select2 is being broken by a plugin or the theme. Usually it is a Fusion theme or a page building plugin.